# What truly constitutes a Databricks managed table?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

All over the place you read a managed table is a table that is created in the default location (/user/hive/warehouse/)

But ***Databricks_own_examples_in_documentation*** creates a managed table in /user/blabla/bla

So what TRULY constitutes a managed table?
It certainly isn't simple anything created on the default database.
The remark, "A managed table is just something we create without the 'LOCATION' keyword"  is ... not exactly correct.

Is it anything written in `/user`?

Is it any table that reads a source on `/user`?
.. If this is true then when I read a file from `/mnt/mymount/fil.csv` to create `tmpView` then
`create table myTable as select * from tmpView`
to re-write it to the default managed location, why is `myTable` still an external table?

What REALLY defines a managed table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There it is.

**If_I_create_a_`DATABASE`*with_a*_`LOCATION`_value**

then every table in this database I create without a `LOCATION` values is a managed table.

But the table will be a subdirectory of a database's location regardless of the cluster's default location for the user Hive warehouse.

Certainly a small but useful nuance.